# Query a Firestore Map property inside a document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection (groups) with documents that has multiple properties, one of them (members) is an array of Maps with the following structure:

```
members:[{"is_admin":true,"user":"users/someuserid"}]
```

When "members" was an array of references (to user documents) it was easy to find all the groups a user is member of:

```
   db.collection("groups").whereField("members", arrayContains: db.document("users/"+UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "firebase_uid")!) ).getDocuments(){
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing (get all the group documents a user is member of) but I can't find the right way to query the inside of the map property.

Comment: Can you more clearly define your structure? Why are you storing an array of maps?

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't do this type of query with Firestore.  You can only match the entire contents of some object in an array, not a specific field in an object in an array.  If you want to match an array field containing exactly `{"is_admin":true,"user":"users/someuserid"}`, you should be able to do that.  You will have to provide the exact fields of *all* the fields of the object to search for.

If you want to just find documents with a particular string value, consider breaking that value out into its own field in order to make it possible to index and search.

Comment: this was two years ago,, any updates ? is it still impossible ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there has been an update sometime in firebase

now you can say :-

i come from dart so syntax will be different below

```
CollectionReference _collectionReference= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups');

String _searchingForThisUserID = users/someuserid; // which is the value u were looking for

QuerySnapshot _collectionSnapshot = await _collectionReference
    .where('anotherFieldNameIfYouWant', isEqualTo: 'otherValueIfYouWant')
    .where('members.user', isEqualTo: '_searchingForThisUserID ')
    .get();
```

I guess you will get my point here regardless the syntax

you will see this `members.user` how I could access a value of a map inside firebase array by this map's field name